# Bootstrap input group with Mathjax

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, mathjax

When adding a [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) formular to a Bootstrap v4 input group, the elements are not align correctly. There is a small step between the label and the input.

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>Without Mathjax everything works fine</p>
  <div class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon">X1</span>
   <input type="number" class="form-control">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>With Mathjax there is a step at the bottom</p>
  <div class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon">\( x_1 \)</span>
   <input type="number" class="form-control">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Edit: This problem occurs with Chrome and a zoom level of 90% and 125% or greater.

[image: Screenshot of the problem with Chrome]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your complaint.  Do you mean that the 1 is lower than the *x*?  Note that that is the correct result, since `x_1` means *x* with a subscript of 1, and subscripts are placed below the baseline.  If that isn't what you mean, you will need to be more explicit about what the issue is.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed this problem occurs with firefox but not with edge. I can test more browser later. The problem is, that the height of the input field is a bit smaller than the span.

Comment: OK, thanks for the extra info.  It doesn't occur for me in Safari or Firefox on Mac OS X, which is why I didn't see it.

Comment: It may have to do with the timing of when MathJax runs in relation to the code that handles the input group.  If the input group is created before MathJax runs, the height will be that of the original input, not the typeset math, and when MathJax later typesets the label, it will get taller, leaving the input area too small.

Comment: Hm, that would explain the problem, because MathJax takes some time before switching the code with formulars. But why does it work with other browsers and can I fix it on Chrome? (I added a screenshot of the problem)

Comment: What happens when you zoom in and out?  Is the step *always* there, and is it always the same relative size?

Comment: Oh, I had 125% zoom all the time. It's fine with 100% and 110% zoom but fails with 90% and above 110%. It did not notice my default zooming settings. That is good, but still, shouldn't it working on all zoom levels? It works work with Edge regardless of the zooming level.

Comment: MathJax uses dimensions given in terms of the font-relative `em` rather than an absolute `px`.  When the browser converts these to px, that means they have to be rounded, and that rounding is a source of differences of this type.  MathJax tries to round its em's to px, but its determination of the px-to-em ratio is empirical, and not perfect.  When a zoom is in effect, this is compounded because the `px` is scaled so no longer matches actual pixels on screen.  That means there is an additional level of rounding done by the browser. ...

Comment: Two elements with slightly different heights may both be rounded the same direction at one zoom level, but may be rounded in opposite directions at a different zoom.  I believe that is what you are seeing here.  MathJax has tried to minimize this, but it is inherent in the way sub-pixel values work, and there isn't really any way that I know of to avoid it completely.

Comment: PS, Chrome has been particularly subject to roundoff errors of this type.

Comment: Okay thank you for the explanation. I just noticed, that this problem also exists with 100% zoom and smaller input fields. Which still fits to your explanation. It think this is a problem I can live with. It's not optimal, but okay. Thanks again!

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.